# High resolution map in R and plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, maps

The resolution argument in plotly doesn't seem to have any impact on my maps

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)


df <- data.frame("lon"=c(134.26,132.40,
                         132.96,132.96,134.03),
                 "lat"=c(33.52,33.38,
                         33.98,32.80,34.04))
points.sf <- st_as_sf(df, coords=c("lon","lat"))
st_crs(points.sf) <- 4326

g <- list(
  fitbounds = "locations", projection = list(type = 'mollweide'),
  showland = TRUE,landcolor = "white",
  showocean=TRUE, oceancolor="LightBlue",
  resolution=1000
)

points.sf %>% plot_geo() %>% layout(geo = g)
```

The outline map remains the same (low resolution) whether I set  the resolution value to 1 or 10000. Is this a plotly limitation? Cross posting at GIS stackexchange: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/475642/high-resolution-map-in-r-and-plotly

Comment: Please do not cross post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/356669 (unless there is a legitimate reason).

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, resolution looks numeric but it actually has ONLY two values: 50 and 110. Other values invalidate the entire argument. It's actually a high/low binary without an error message.